# foreach loop inside while loop in php gives unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I have been trying this for the past couple of hours to get it right. Dynamic Checkbox from database. I am trying to get the value out from the foreach loop. Can anyone help me on this.

```
$sql_child = "SELECT muploadid, mupload_filename FROM nattachment na LEFT JOIN multipleupload mu ON mu.mupload_id = na.muploadid WHERE na.notetestid = '$id'";
$result_child = mysqli_query($con, $sql_child);

    $childArrayFilename = array();
    while($row_child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_child)){
        $childArrayId[] = $row_child['muploadid'];
        $childArrayFilename[] = $row_child['mupload_filename'];
    }

$sql_parent = "SELECT mupload_filename FROM multipleupload";
$result_parent = mysqli_query($con, $sql_parent);
?>

<form action="database/db_update.php" method="POST">
    <?php
    while($row_parent = mysqli_fetch_array($result_parent)) {
        if(in_array($row_parent['mupload_filename'], $childArrayFilename)) {

           // foreach((array)$childArrayFilename as $result) { REMOVED
                echo "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='".$result."'checked='checked'/> ";
                echo "<input name='checkbox_hid[]' type='hidden' value='".$result."'checked='checked'/> ";
           // } REMOVED
        }
        else {
            echo "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row_parent['mupload_filename']."'/> ";
            echo "<input name='checkbox_hid[]' type='hidden' value='".$row_parent['mupload_filename']."'/> ";
        }
        echo $row_parent['mupload_filename'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="fm_submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Using forloop i get something like this. Currently there are three checkbox selected and they repeated in a row.

```
.----------.------------.-----.------------.
|   [✓]    |    [✓]     | [✓] |  ch7.jpg   |
:----------+------------+-----+------------:
|   [ ]    | tutor1.jpg                    |
:----------+------------+-----+------------:
|   [✓]    |    [✓]     | [✓] | tutor2.jpg |
:----------+------------+-----+------------:
|   [ ]    | ch1.jpg                       |
:----------+------------+-----+------------:
|   [ ]    | ch2.jpg                       |
:----------+------------+-----+------------:
|   [✓]    |    [✓]     | [✓] | ch3.jpg    |
:----------+------------+-----+------------:
|   [ ]    | ch4.jpg                       |
:----------+------------+-----+------------:
| [Submit] |                               |
'----------'------------'-----'------------'
```

I need this.

```
.----------.------------.
|   [✓]    |  ch7.jpg   |
:----------+------------:
|   [ ]    | tutor1.jpg |
:----------+------------:
|   [✓]    | tutor2.jpg |
:----------+------------:
|   [ ]    | ch1.jpg    |
:----------+------------:
|   [ ]    | ch2.jpg    |
:----------+------------:
|   [✓]    | ch3.jpg    |
:----------+------------:
|   [ ]    | ch4.jpg    |
:----------+------------:
| [Submit] |            |
'----------'------------'
```

Comment: To my understanding you don't need the foreach loop

Comment: I need to get the value out from the input field. how do i do that.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for that. I fixed it.

Comment: Ain't that the same as `$row_parent['mupload_filename']`? Try echoing that instead and tell me if it works

Comment: yes it works. you are right.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation (or variable substitution) for building SQL queries, ESPECIALLY not if the variable in question comes from user input.  You'll be exposing yourself to SQL Injection Attacks.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @GordonM Will definitely consider. Thanks.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

using         $selected = in_array($row_parent['mupload_filename'], $childArrayFilename); you can avoid if else loop which is not much readable.

```
    $sql_child = "SELECT muploadid, mupload_filename FROM nattachment na LEFT JOIN multipleupload mu ON mu.mupload_id = na.muploadid WHERE na.notetestid = '$id'";
$result_child = mysqli_query($con, $sql_child);

    $childArrayFilename = array();
    while($row_child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_child)){
        $childArrayId[] = $row_child['muploadid'];
        $childArrayFilename[] = $row_child['mupload_filename'];
    }

$sql_parent = "SELECT mupload_filename FROM multipleupload";
$result_parent = mysqli_query($con, $sql_parent);
?>

<form action="database/db_update.php" method="POST">
    <?php
    while($row_parent = mysqli_fetch_array($result_parent)) {
        $selected = in_array($row_parent['mupload_filename'], $childArrayFilename);
                echo "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row_parent['mupload_filename']."'". $selected ? "checked='checked'  /> " : " /> ";
               echo "<input name='checkbox_hid[]' type='hidden' value='".$row_parent['mupload_filename']."'". $selected ? "checked='checked'  /> " : " /> ";
        echo $row_parent['mupload_filename'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="fm_submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: You just pasted some code with no explanation whatsoever on a question that should be closed as a typo/unable to reproduce...

Comment: Code is self explanatory. I have made it simple.

Comment: Nothing about this is self-explanatory. Please, when posting code always add remarks on what you changed, why you changed things, or what the problem is. It doesn't have to be a lot of text, a single sentence often does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fixed after removing the for loop and added the parent id to it.

```
// foreach((array)$childArrayFilename as $result) { REMOVED
    echo "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row_parent['mupload_id']."'checked='checked'/> ";
    echo "<input name='checkbox_hid[]' type='hidden' value='".$row_parent['mupload_id']."'checked='checked'/> ";
// } REMOVED
```